# How to remove gridlines in a GeoBubbleChart

Tags: geographics

Assume that LargeRegionalCities is a list of, say, US cities. I would like to remove the gridlines in the code below:

```
GeoBubbleChart[
 LargeRegionalCities -> 
  QuantityArray[EntityValue[LargeRegionalCities, "Population"]], 
 ChartLabels -> LargeRegionalCities,
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18],
 GeoBackground -> 
  GeoStyling[{"CountryBorders", "Land" -> GrayLevel[0.6], 
    "Ocean" -> GrayLevel[0.3], "Border" -> Black}],
 GeoZoomLevel -> 10,
 ChartStyle -> "SolarColors",
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing",
 GridLinesStyle -> None,
 BubbleSizes -> {0.05, 0.07}
 ]
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `GeoGridLines` and/or `GeoGridLinesStyle`:

```
largeRegionalCities = 
 EntityClass[
  "City", {EntityProperty["City", "Country"] -> 
    Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
   EntityProperty["City", "Population"] -> TakeLargest[5]}];

GeoBubbleChart[
 largeRegionalCities -> 
  QuantityArray[EntityValue[largeRegionalCities, "Population"]], 
 ChartLabels -> largeRegionalCities, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18], 
 GeoBackground -> 
  GeoStyling[{"CountryBorders", "Land" -> GrayLevel[0.6], 
    "Ocean" -> GrayLevel[0.3], "Border" -> Black}], 
 GeoZoomLevel -> 10, ChartStyle -> "SolarColors", 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", BubbleSizes -> {0.05, 0.07}, 
 GeoGridLines -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `PlotTheme` option or use `"Business"` theme instead of `"Marketing"` to get the desired result:

```
GeoBubbleChart[largeRegionalCities -> 
  QuantityArray[EntityValue[largeRegionalCities, "Population"]], 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[EntityList@largeRegionalCities, Above], 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18], 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"CountryBorders", "Land" -> GrayLevel[0.6], 
    "Ocean" -> GrayLevel[0.3], "Border" -> Black}], 
 GeoZoomLevel -> 10, ChartStyle -> "SolarColors", 
 BubbleSizes -> {0.05, 0.07}]
```

[image]

```
GeoBubbleChart[largeRegionalCities -> 
  QuantityArray[EntityValue[largeRegionalCities, "Population"]], 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[EntityList @ largeRegionalCities, Above], 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18], 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"CountryBorders", "Land" -> GrayLevel[0.6], 
    "Ocean" -> GrayLevel[0.3], "Border" -> Black}], 
 GeoZoomLevel -> 10, ChartStyle -> "SolarColors", 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", BubbleSizes -> {0.05, 0.07}]
```

[image]

**Note:** Inspecting the styling options of the three themes (`Automatic` (default), `"Marketing"` and `"Business"`) using `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme ``

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, GeoBubbleChart]
```

[image]

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Marketing", GeoBubbleChart]
```

[image]

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Business", GeoBubbleChart]
```

[image]

we see that `"Marketing"` theme adds the `GeoBackground` option (which you have already overridden in your code) and `GeoGridLines` option (which you don`t want). Since you also specify the bubble colors there is no need to use a non-default theme.